# Avoid colours of white space

Tags: whitespace

[image]

Added a lot of stuff to my vimrc lately and I am not sure what is causing vim to colour the whitespaces. The colour disappears when I save the file. However I would like to disable this feature. Is there any way to do so?

```
set nocompatible " Use Vim settings, rather than Vi settings
set softtabstop=2 " Indent by 2 spaces when hitting tab
set shiftwidth=4 " Indent by 4 spaces when auto-indenting
set tabstop=4 " Show existing tab with 4 spaces width
syntax on " Enable syntax highlighting
filetype indent on " Enable indenting for files
set autoindent " Enable auto indenting
set number
set relativenumber " Enable relative numbers
set nobackup " Disable backup files
set laststatus=1 "show status line
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w%=(%{&ff}/%Y)\ (line\ %l\/%L,\ col\ %c)\
set wildmenu " Display command line's tab complete options as a menu.
set hlsearch
set title

" Move visual selection
vnoremap J :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap K :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv

" Relative numbers in normal mode only
augroup toggle_relative_number
autocmd InsertEnter * :setlocal norelativenumber
autocmd InsertLeave * :setlocal relativenumber

let mapleader = "\<Space>"
nnoremap t :w<CR>

" highlight trailing whitespace
match ErrorMsg '\s\+$'
" remove trailing whitespaces automatically
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e

" TAB Completion
function! Smart_TabComplete()
  let line = getline('.')                         " current line

  let substr = strpart(line, -1, col('.')+1)      " from the start of the current
                                                  " line to one character right
                                                  " of the cursor
  let substr = matchstr(substr, "[^ \t]*$")       " word till cursor
  if (strlen(substr)==0)                          " nothing to match on empty string
    return "\<tab>"
  endif
  let has_period = match(substr, '\.') != -1      " position of period, if any
  let has_slash = match(substr, '\/') != -1       " position of slash, if any
  if (!has_period && !has_slash)
    return "\<C-X>\<C-P>"                         " existing text matching
  elseif ( has_slash )
    return "\<C-X>\<C-F>"                         " file matching
  else
    return "\<C-X>\<C-O>"                         " plugin matching
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <tab> <c-r>=Smart_TabComplete()<CR>

nnoremap <Leader>O O<ESC>
nnoremap <Leader>o o<ESC>
nnoremap <Leader>d /some_random_text<CR>

vnoremap F "+y
```

Comment: This describes an efficient way to find the culprit in your config: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003) If you find the cause but still aren't sure how to disable the coloring let us know the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
" highlight trailing whitespace
match ErrorMsg '\s\+$'
" remove trailing whitespaces automatically
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e
```

If you don't need this behaviour you described